# Customizing color palette of tinymce

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

How do i go on about customizing a color palette in tinymce to look like the image below?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYC8J.jpg)

I am using tinymce v5. Since the textcolor plugin is now enabled by default, my old code for customizing the palette is nt working anymore.

I would appreciate any idea

Answer (score 2):

The colors can be set using the [color_map](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#color_map) setting. It is a list of paired hexadecimal colors without the leading # followed by a name.

Here is an example:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  toolbar: 'forecolor backcolor',
  color_map: [
    '000000', 'Black',
    '808080', 'Gray',
    'FFFFFF', 'White',
    'FF0000', 'Red',
    'FFFF00', 'Yellow',
    '008000', 'Green',
    '0000FF', 'Blue'
  ]
});
```